# Released app behaves differently from debug binary on same devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, xcode6

My app has just been approved by Apple, but it behaves differently from when I run it in debug mode on the same devices.

I suspect there's something wonky going on with the transition from 32 bit to 64 bit datatypes since the recent 64 bit requirements from Apple, but I don't know how to test this other than running the app on actual 32 bit and 64 bit devices!

In this case something odd is going on when sampling colors from an image where the resulting colors used to end up in a float and now in a CGFloat. But as said, it works perfectly on all devices when debugging but goes south in the 'official' appstore approved binary.

How to test? Or do I have to do this through trial and error?

Comment: Try AdHoc distribution and test in actual device. AdHoc has same release configuration

Comment: And also check you don't have any debug macros defined for debug verison..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, here's how to test the actual binary you're submitting to Apple:

1. Build and Archive your project
2. From the Archive window (the one where you would normally submit your app to Apple for review): export the app file (ipa) to your desktop
3. Open iTunes and connect your iDevice (note: the device has to be registered for testing; if you can also use it from XCode you're good to go)
4. Drag the ipa from your computer onto your device in iTunes and Sync to make sure it actually ends up on the device
5. Run your app from the iDevice

I'm not sure if there is a difference between this method and running the app from XCode using the "Release" build-scheme, but this is as close as you can get to running the actual binary Apple will receive for reviewing.